# Windows 10 Task Manager RAM Slots Indicator

Tags: windows-10, memory

In Windows 10, on the performance tab, under memory in task manager, it says "Slots used: 1 of 2"

I was wondering if this is reliable.  Searching my laptop online suggests that it only has one slot. Is it worth buying an extra stick of RAM or should I open it up first to check?

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing the specific model of laptop that you have, this is not possible to answer authoritatively. If you want an authoritative answer, please edit your question to mention the specific make and model laptop that you have.

*However,* we can say in general that on modern systems, the relevant data is available through [DMI and SMBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Management_Interface), which can be queried from software. This includes the number of memory slots on the motherboard and the hardware installed in those slots. So yes, if the BIOS isn't outright lying, **the data shown *should* be reliable.**

It seems quite possible that your laptop has one memory module soldered to the motherboard, and one expansion slot available for expansion. This would show up as two slots to software querying for memory hardware data, but only one of those would be available for you to use or not as you please, so might be listed online as "one memory slot, one slot available" or similar.

That said, the only way to be 100% sure is to open up the laptop and look at the motherboard. You can however get pretty close by looking at the vendor's specifications for the model that you have. Look specifically for data on permanently mounted RAM vs available RAM expansion slots.